# SQL Server 2008 Index Fragment

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, database-performance, database-tuning

I have a table with more than 5,000,000 records. The SQL Query performance on this table impacted by index fragment a lot. Looks like everyday, the fragment increasing so fast. 
I need to rebuild index every day for user's complain.

How to figure it out the possible reason? How to resolve this issue?
Is it a hardware issue or need recreate the table with partition option?

Comment: First question: do you have a clustered index on that table, and if so, on what column (what datatype does the column have)?

Comment: Yes, I have one clustered index(type: int) on this table and 2 non-cluster index(also on int) and one PK index(int too).

Comment: What are the actual table and index definitions? Also [per my comments on this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19998471/73226) what you have told us so far doesn't necessarily point to the fragmentation being the issue.

Comment: Per the information given here I recommend the same counter-measures that I would always recommend against fragmentation. They are well-documented on the web. Search: "SQL Server fragmentation mitigation".